# Mask UIView Which Is Transformed

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, transform

I have a UIView which i did transform using

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale
```

Now my view is bigger then its rect in which is was located in and it falls over all my views.

Is there a way to put a mask on my transformed view, so only the part of the transformed view which fits inside the rect from before the transformation is being displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say it is bigger than the `rect` it is located in, I am assuming you are talking of the parent view. You should be able to do `parentView.clipsToBounds = YES;` to restrict the view within its parent view.